# Calculus: Is an endpoint a singular point?

Tags: calculus

My question is: is an endpoint a singular point?

From the definition of a singular point:

a point $x$ belongs to dom($f$) such that $f'(x)$ is not defined.

I guess the endpoint is not defined for $f'(x)$ so it is a singular point, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrong, but you are not right. Usually endpoints (of an interval) are not considered to be singular points for a function, since the derivative fails to exist for a rather weak reason. Actually, at the endpoints you can always define directional derivatives (i.e. the left derivative and the right derivative, as appropriate).

Singular points should be, in principle, points where $f$ is continuous but non-differentiable. For this reason some authors restrict singular points to *interior* points. Anyway, an endpoint could be singular, if the appropriate one-sided derivative fails to exist *but* the function is continuous at that point.

Comment: So if I were to answer a question: find all the singular points of the function I would not mention the end points?

Comment: It depends on your definition. By the way, why do people bot define what they use? The definition you propose is very unclear, since the domain of $f$ can be any set. On the contrary, derivatives are defined, in general, only at interior points.